# Like "Deceitful" but stating something as a fact, while witholding the truth

Tags: single-word-requests

What is this called? It's not: Deceitful, misleading, deceptive, equivocal, etc.

It's like deceiving/ gaslighting but a different word.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is neither of these words. I think it started with 'N'?

Answer (score 0):

> It's like deceiving/ gaslighting but a different word.

**misdirect** (v.)

> To direct attention away from covert actions or intended targets. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misdirect)

---

> He might not be able to lie, but he was able to **misdirect** like it
> was an art.  [Tiffany Buckner; *Sex, Lies and Soul Ties*](http://Q)

> It wasn't an answer and it wasn't a lie, but it was **misdirection**.
> [Jake Adelstein; *Tokyo Vice*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Tokyo_Vice/1amOE2BYvIYC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=misdirection%20wasn%27t%20a%20lie&pg=PA51&printsec=frontcover)

> His shifting Noah to our world isn't a malign act; His
> **misdirecting** Noah away from understanding that isn't either. He did not lie to or harm Noah; He said, “Get on the boat. Get off the
> boat.” He never promised He would explain. [David Brown; *The Noatic
> Crossing*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Noatic_Crossing/3LmIDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=not%20a%20lie%20but%20to%20misdirect%20away%20from&pg=PT81&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 0):

You can say he or she is pathologically mendacious...

“Mendacious.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mendacious. Accessed 4 Nov. 2021.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).